# Question doesn't properly display

Tags: bug, code-formatting

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32731939/3749523) doesn't properly display its contents; it seems like a bug to me. If you *edit* the question, you'll notice that there is a whole lot more code in there which isn't shown when viewing it. The edit preview also has some problems with it, only parts are shown (but more than what is shown normally)

It seems to be caused by the unformatted `<?php`, all lines following it disappear. Is this somehow interpreted as an HTML tag?

Comment: Not a bug. The lines of code don't have four spaces before them.

Comment: That doesn't explain why code like `require('lib/nusoap.php');` disappears as well (instead of appearing non-formatted)

Comment: Oh that. Tags that are not HTML tags disappear (`<?php ...$client->`).

Comment: I'd say that is buggy. It's kind of obvious that `<?php\n\n...>` shouldn't be interpreted as HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this has been answered before, but if you post something that looks like an HTML tag, but actually isn't (or isn't supported by SE's MarkDown), it won't get rendered in the final HTML.

So the unformatted `<?php ... $client->` is seen as an unknown HTML tag.